# Is there a Java library to cache files?

Tags: java, caching, filesystems, memcached, cache-control

Is there are java library that will cache files to memory and disk?  Basically, I would like the library to cache the file to memory.  However, if the in memory cache gets larger than a certain threshhold, some of the files should be written to disk.

Is there any Java library that will do this?

Grae

Update:

Just a couple general comment.

I am only going to using these files once. They are just temp files.  In a perfect world, I would keep them all in memory.  However, I think I would run out of memory.  What I guess I am really looking for is some sort of paging system.  That can keep me form running out of memory, but also allow me to avoid writting everyhting to disk.

Comment: In all likelihood, your OS already uses otherwise-unused memory to cache files. In what ways do you find that mechanism unsatisfactory?

Comment: Essentially every non-embedded OS handles this behind-the-scenes; is there a specific performance problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @aix If I just write the files to memory,  I will run out of heap memory.

Comment: @Grae, How does writing to files, use heap memory?

Comment: @Peter Lawrey I should have been more clear.   Normally, I would just keep the entire file in memory.  However, when too many files are in memory at once, I would like the library to automatically, page some of the files to disk.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, try Terracotta or EhCache.  Or Google for "java cache" and pick something else.

Comment: (I think everything but ehcache-core pretty much gives you terracotta now anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

The OS caches files automatically.  It will also automatically keep in the memory the most recently used portions of files (it can partially cache a file)  I suggest you let the OS do the caching for you and find a way to efficient get data between Java and the OS.

Comment: The problem with this is I have to first write the entire file to disk.  I would like if possibke to avoid this first right.

Comment: When you write data to disk, it goes into the OSes write cache and migrates to physical disk when it can. (Committing it to disk and knowing it has actually been written is not supported in Java IO. There is FileChannel.force() to do this in NIO. If you use `tmpfs` on unix, it might not even do that.

Comment: I guess what I am trying to say is I don't want to write the files to disk, when possible.  Most of the time it should not be needed to write the files to disk.

Comment: I assume your probably right that the files are auomatically put in the OS's cache, and they not necessarily put in the physical disk right away.  However, once I write the file, I have to assume it can get written to disk.  I am trying to avoid any writing to disk. I only want the application to write to disk when my application is out of memory or nearly out of memory.

Comment: When it is nearly out, it may not be able to reclaim memory fast enough (you would be limited by the speed of the disk) If most of the data is already on disk which you run low, you won't have the same problem. I suggest you look at memory mapped files which blur the lines between what is in memory and what is on disk only.

Comment: With mapped memory files, I think I would still have to write the entire file to disk, before I can read from the file.  Is that correct?

Comment: Memory mapped files cheat in this regard. If you make the size say 1 GB, it creates sparse files which doesn't actually consume this much space on disk until you use the pages in the file. i.e. the disk  space free won't change immediately, even though the files will say they are the size you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I have had good luck with ehcache. It is very configurable.

Comment: Do you have some idea of where to start?  I am not really trying to cache one file many uses.  I just want to cache a file disk, when I run out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

[Open Source Cache Solutions in Java](http://java-source.net/open-source/cache-solutions)